# .net Regex for more than 2 consecutive letters

Tags: .net, regex

I am attempting to write a .Net Regex for more than 2 consecutives letters.

```
aa - fine
Aa - fine
aaa - not allowed
Aaa - not allowed
```

I am new to regex, but this is what I have pieced together so far.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(Password, @"/[^A-Za-z]{2}/"))
    return "Password cannot contain 3 consecutive same letters";
```

I am not sure if this is close or not.

Comment: I think what you looking for is simply `(.)\1\1`. The regex you have will match 2 any letters like `ab`.

Comment: @Ilia G - `(.)\1\1` works for `AAA` and `aaa`, but NOT `Aaa` or `aaA`. D'oh!

Comment: @ridgerunner `Regex.Match("bOooga", @"(.)\1\1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` Alternativelly you could upper/lower case the input before running the regex like ruakh did.

Comment: @Ilia G - No, just adding `IgnoreCase` will not fix this. The single char that is captured in `$1` is either lower or upper and `\1` will be always be the exact same letter. The expression: `(.)\1\1` can only match the same one character, three times in a row. The only way that this expressions will work is if the string is first forced to all-upper or all-lower case befor performing the match.

Comment: @ridgerunner The code snippet I posted works as is. Feel free to try it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the slashes (why are they there? this is not PHP) and you could use the ignore case flag. Like:

```
Regex.Match(pw, @"(?i)(.)\1\1")
```

Which is same as:

```
Regex.Match(pw, @"(.)\1\1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

As commented by Ilia G.

Comment: oh cool, didn't know you can embed options into regex itself.