# RegEx No more than 2 identical consecutive characters and a-Z and 0-9

Tags: regex

**Edit**: Thanks for the advice to make my question clearer :)

The `Match` is looking for 3 consecutive characters:

`Regex Match =`**AaA**`653219`
`Regex Match = AA`**555**`6219`

The code is ASP.NET 4.0. Here is the whole function:

```
public ValidationResult ApplyValidationRules()
{
    ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult();
    Regex regEx = new Regex(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,20}$");

    bool valid = regEx.IsMatch(_Password);
    if (!valid)
        result.Errors.Add("Passwords must be 8-20 characters in length, contain at least one alpha character and one numeric character");

    return result;
}
```

I've tried for over 3 hours to make this work, referencing the below with no luck =/

[How can I find repeated characters with a regex in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664194/how-can-i-find-repeated-characters-with-a-regex-in-java)

[.net Regex for more than 2 consecutive letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760443/net-regex-for-more-than-2-consecutive-letters)

I have started with this for 8-20 characters `a-Z` `0-9` :

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,20}$
```

```vb
As Regex regEx = new Regex(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,20}$");
```

I've tried adding variations of the below with no luck:

```
/(.)\1{9,}/
.*([0-9A-Za-z])\\1+.*
((\\w)\\2+)+".
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Post a sample input and the expected matches.

Comment: What is the language? VB.NET?

Comment: Does this have to be a single regular expression? It sounds like you just need to check for strings that match `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}` and also do _not_ match `.*(.)\1\1.*`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

http://regexr.com?34vo9

The regular expression:

```
^(?=.{8,20}$)(([a-z0-9])\2?(?!\2))+$
```

The first lookahead (`(?=.{8,20}$)`) checks the length of your string.  The second portion does your double character and validity checking by:

```
(
  ([a-z0-9])      Matching a character and storing it in a back reference.
  \2?             Optionally match one more EXACT COPY of that character.
  (?!\2)          Make sure the upcoming character is NOT the same character.
)+                Do this ad nauseum.
$                 End of string.
```

Okay.  I see you've added some additional requirements.  My basic forumla still works, but we have to give you more of a step by step approach.  SO:

```
^...$
```

Your whole regular expression will be dropped into start and end characters, for obvious reasons.

```
(?=.{n,m}$)
```

Length checking.  Put this at the beginning of your regular expression with n as your minimum length and m as your maximum length.

```
(?=(?:[^REQ]*[REQ]){n,m})
```

Required characters.  Place this at the beginning of your regular expression with REQ as your required character to require N to M of your character.  YOu may drop the `(?: ..){n,m}` to require just one of that character.

```
(?:([VALID])\1?(?!\1))+
```

The rest of your expression.  Replace VALID with your valid Characters.  So, your Password Regex is:

```
^(?=.{8,20}$)(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?:([\w\d*?!:;])\1?(?!\1))+$
```

'Splained:

```
^
  (?=.{8,20}$)                 8 to 20 characters
  (?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])       At least one Alpha
  (?=[^0-9]*[0-9])             At least one Numeric
  (?:([\w\d*?!:;])\1?(?!\1))+  Valid Characters, not repeated thrice.
$
```

http://regexr.com?34vol  Here's the new one in action.

Comment: @TacRedline  You're Welcome.  I've added instructions for a bake your own validator RegEx that should allow you to do all your extra stuff.  This stuff gets pretty unreadable pretty fast though - you may want to compile it in parts for better self documentation, or provide a lot of Comments.  Feel free to mark this answer as "accepted" if it answered your question.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan I tried to use regex with predicate for consecutive character but when there is two repetitive character I am getting "True" but in case of three or more than two consecutive character I am getting false. here is my code,                                             let consecutiveRegEx = "(?:([\\w\\d*?!:;])\\1?(?!\\1))+$"
        let pred  = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@ ", consecutiveRegEx)
        debugPrint(" isConNumber - \(pred.evaluate(with: password))")

Answer (score 1):

Tightened up matching criteria as it was too broad; for example, "not A-Za-z" matches a lot more than is intended.  The previous REGEX was matching on the string "ThiIsNot". For the most part, passwords are only going to contain alphanumeric and punctation characters, so I limited the scope, which made all matches more accurate.  Used character classes for human readability.  Added and exclusion list, and differentiated upper and lower case letters.

```
^(?=.{8,20}$)(?!(?:.*[01IiLlOo]))(?=(?:[\[[:digit:]\]\[[:punct:]\]]*[\[[:alpha:]\]]){2})(?=(?:[\[[:digit:]\]\[[:punct:]\]\[[:upper:]\]]*[\[[:lower:]\]]){1})(?=(?:[\[[:digit:]\]\[[:punct:]\]\[[:lower:]\]]*[\[[:upper:]\]]){1})(?=(?:[\[[:alpha:]\]\[[:punct:]\]]*[\[[:digit:]\]]){1})(?=(?:[\[[:alnum:]\]]*[\[[:punct:]\]]){1})(?:([\[[:alnum:]\]\[[:punct:]\]])\1?(?!\1))+$
```

The breakdown:

```
^(?=.{8,20}$) - Positive lookahead that the string is between 8 and 20 chars
(?!(?:.*[01IiLlOo])) - Negative lookahead for any blacklisted chars
(?=(?:[\[[:digit:]\]\[[:punct:]\]]*[\[[:alpha:]\]]){2}) - Verify that at least 2 alpha chars exist
(?=(?:[\[[:digit:]\]\[[:punct:]\]\[[:upper:]\]]*[\[[:lower:]\]]){1}) - Verify that at least 1 lowercase alpha exists
(?=(?:[\[[:digit:]\]\[[:punct:]\]\[[:lower:]\]]*[\[[:upper:]\]]){1}) - Verify that at least 1 uppercase alpha exists
(?=(?:[\[[:alpha:]\]\[[:punct:]\]]*[\[[:digit:]\]]){1}) - Verify that at least 1 digit exists
(?=(?:[\[[:alnum:]\]]*[\[[:punct:]\]]){1}) - Verify that at least 1 special/punctuation char exists
(?:([\[[:alnum:]\]\[[:punct:]\]])\1?(?!\1))+$ - Verify that no char is repeated more than twice in a row
```