# Matching consecutive characters with password limitation

Tags: regex

Hello guys I'm trying to match the following regex:

- Minimum characters: 8
- Maximum characters: 22
- Minimum uppercase letters: 1
- Minimum lowercase letters: 1
- Minimum digits: 2
- Special characters are allowed
- First character must be a letter
- Maximum consecutive identical characters: 2

I've manage to complete every condition but the consecutive ones with:

```
(?=^.{8,22}$)(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]))^[a-zA-Z].*$
```

Following the post [RegEx No more than 2 identical consecutive characters and a-Z and 0-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717656/regex-no-more-than-2-identical-consecutive-characters-and-a-z-and-0-9) I've seen that the way of not matching exact characters is:

```
((.)\2?(?!\2))+
```

But I'm unable to mix them both and have the full matching result. The tries are being done here: https://regex101.com/r/94KaXO/1/ where the first string should match but not the second one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=.{8,22}$)(?!.*(.)\1{2})(?=(?:\D*\d){2})(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])[a-zA-Z].*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/er8ZII/1/).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{8,22}$)` - 8 to 22 chars other than line break chars are allowed in the string
- **`(?!.*(.)\1{2})` - no 3 consecutive identical chars allowed anywhere after zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible**
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){2})` - there must be at least 2 not necessarily consecutive digits in the string
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - there must be at least one uppercase letter in the string
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - there must be at least 2 one lowercase letter in the string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$`- end of string.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. Can you give me a brief explanation of what did you changed and why? Thanks

Comment: @SergioGonzález The *no 3 consecutive identical chars allowed* lookahead (`(?!.*(.)\1{2})`) is what you were missing. Note the [principle of contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast), too.